# DataContext property bound to TextBox.Text doesn't update when the TextBox is cleared

Tags: c#, silverlight

In my `SilverLight` application I have a `TextBox.Text` bound to a `nullable decimal` of the `DataContext`. When I change the value of the `TextBox` for example from 25 to 6 it works, the property's setter on the `DataContext` is executed and the backing field updated, but when I clear the `TextBox` manually it doesn't work, the setter is not called.

```
[DataMember]
public decimal? Order 
{
    get { return order; }
    set { order = value; }
}
decimal? order;
```

xaml snippet:

```
<Input:PraTextBox
    Text="{Binding Path=Order, Mode=TwoWay}"
    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsDefaultVisibleEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: <Input:PraTextBox IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsDefaultVisibleEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="{Binding Path=Order, Mode=TwoWay}" />

Comment: [DataMember]
        public  decimal? Order 
        {
            get
            {
                return order;
            }
            set
            { 
                order=value;
            }
        }
        decimal? order;

Comment: And when do you clear your textbox? Could you provide that code too?

Comment: I clear it at the runtime not by code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ordinary `TextBox` only updates the binding source on `LostFocus` by default. I don't know what your `PraTextBox` does. But I recommend you check whether it updates the source on `LostFocus` or on `PropertyChanged`.

Try specifying the [UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) inside the binding:

```
Text="{Binding Path=Order, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Next try: use a converter:

```
public class NullableDecimalConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture) { return value; }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string decimalString = value as string;
        decimal parsedDecimal;
        if (decimalString != null && Decimal.TryParse( decimalString,
                                                       out parsedDecimal ))
            return parsedDecimal;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

the binding:

```
Text="{Binding Path=Order, Mode=TwoWay,
    Converter={StaticResource myNullableDecimalConverter}}"
```

Comment: I have already tried to put UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged and it gives this exception "PropertyChanged not found"

Comment: In my situation the TextBox updates the binding source on LostFocus

Comment: Are you using Silverlight 5? Because `UpdateSourceTrigger: PropertyChanged` only came with SL5.

Comment: You said the update happens on LostFocus, does this mean if you clear the `TextBox` and jump out of it with the tab key the update is performed correctly?

Comment: My Silverlight Version is : 4.0.50826.0

Comment: If I change the value of the TextBox for example from 5 to 8 and I jump out of it with tab key or by clicking in another TextBox using the mouse it works fine, the problem is when I clear the TextBox it doesn't update with null value as I want.

Comment: @user2977309: OK, try a converter, I added an implementation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Silverlight (and WPF as long as I know) treat an empty TextBox as an empty string and not null.. Also they believe that empty string conversion to a number is undetermined, so if you bind a number to a textbox, once you set value to the number, you *cannot* clear it anymore.

PropetyChanged doesnt fire simply because the number hasnt changed - get debugger and see it for yourself.

In Silverlight 5 you can use this:

`<TextBox Text="{Binding SOMEFIELD, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue=''}"`

where SOMEFIELD is Nullable or other number..